# iOS: how to calculate value of flux

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

Flux (the amount of light emitted from any given fitting/lamp – measure in lumens)
Is there any way to calculate by getting image from camera or in live video capturing ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way you will need to capture image runtime and analysis that image
Use this algo to check luminosity
http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/obtaining-luminosity-from-an-ios-camera